# How do I properly access the data-attribute of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to have the days of the week appear within my H2 elements but the console says "cannot read property of fday undefined" Below is the HTML elements I'm trying to append to and the JS i'm using to do it

```
<div class="flex-container col-xs-6" id="weekDay">
    <h2 data-fday="1"></h2>
    <h2 data-fday="2"></h2>
    <h2 data-fday="3"></h2>
    <h2 data-fday="4"></h2>
    <h2 data-fday="5"></h2>
</div>

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) { //Begin loop - loop over the object's next 5 days
    const weekly_forecast = data.daily.data;
    let today = moment().format('D MMM, YYYY');//Format the date in the form Day / Month / Year from moment.js library
    const weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

    $('#day_'+[i]).append("<h3>"+weekly_forecast[i].apparentTemperatureMax + "<br></h3><P>" + weekly_forecast[i].summary + "</p>"); //append a <h2> within that div containing the day and <p> containing the high and low temperature for the day
        //Get the day of the week...
    let a = new Date(today); //parse current date
    let nextDay = weekday[a.getDay()+i]; //(get the day of the week)
    const dayData = $("#weekDay > h2").dataset.fday; //accessthe data-attribute of each H2 within #weekday
    if (dayData = [i]) {    //if the data attribute of the H2 element === i
        $(this).append(nextDay);    //append the current day of the week in the H2
    }

    console.log(nextDay);

}
```

Comment: check if `$("#weekDay > h2")` actually returns anything

Comment: `.data('fday')` should work

Comment: @Ted the console shows [h2, h2, h2, h2, h2, prevObject: r.fn.init[1] logged out 6 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataset` is not a jQuery object property, it is a dom element property.

Also you need to target the proper element index within the loop

Try changing

```
$("#weekDay > h2").dataset.fday
```

To

```
$("#weekDay > h2").eq(i).data('fday');
```

Or to access as dom node property

```
$("#weekDay > h2")[i].dataset.fday
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it using PURE JS. Either using dataset or using the getAttribute method.

```js
var test = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
console.log(test[1].dataset.id);
var dataText = test[0].dataset.id + " " + test[1].dataset.id;
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = dataText;


var dataTextAnotherApproach = test[1].getAttribute('data-id');
document.getElementById('target2').innerHTML = dataTextAnotherApproach;
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li data-id="data 1">Hello</li>
    <li data-id="data 2">Hello 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="target"></div>
<div id="target2"></div>
```